# Algorithm to verify if a line is intersect another - javafx

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx

[image]

I have a rectangular and line. I need to verify whether a line is intersect that rectangle.

Does anyone know this kind of algorithm in javafx?

I made rectangular with x, y, width, height.

thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use `intersects`like `rect.getBoundsInParent().intersects(line.getBoundsInParent());`. User [jewelsea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea) has a [nice demo application](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960) about `Shape` collision, you could check out.

Comment: @DVarga Thanks for your answer. I will check out!